# Selenium Chromedriver doesn't keep me logged in in some websites

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, automation, web-crawler

I'm using Selenium and ChromeDriver to scrape data from a website.
I need to **keep my account logged in** after closing the Driver: for this purpose I use every time the default Chrome profile.
Here you can see my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

urlpage = 'https://example.com/'

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\MyName\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get(urlpage)
```

The problem is that for some websites (e.g. https://projecteuler.net/) it works, so I'm logged in also the following session, but for other (like https://www.fundraiso.ch, the one I need) it doesn't, although in the "normal" browser I'm still logged in after I close the window.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

**EDIT**:
I didn't mention that I can't automate the login because the website has a maximum login number, and if I breach it the website will block my account.

Comment: Any values that are saved to disk by the browser (session/remember me stored values/cookies) will be deleted when the driver quits.  A temporary folder is created for this... (I believe it's in app_data/temp.)

Comment: That happens just for fundraiso.ch. As I said, when I quit and then I reopen the browser I'm still logged in in projecteuler.net

Comment: Your original profile may have a "remember me" type value stored from a normal session for the one site, but not the other.

Comment: You are right. So how can I achieve my goal (keep me logged in)?

Comment: You can manually login and check the box for "remember me". If the site doesn't have that option, you need to automate the login for each new session. Either way you'll always have a new and temporary session per driver.... so you'd need to run a site-specific javascript to sort of steal your own session (cookie/token, etc...) and re-use.

Comment: I can't automate the login because the website has a maximum login number, and if I breach it the website will block my account. The solution of the site-specific javascript seems difficult to implement. Aren’t there easier ways to do that?

Comment: Keep the driver open, maybe?  Hopefully someone else will have an answer.  Selenium does have commands for importing/exporting cookies, but not sure if this would work across sessions:  https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/support_packages/working_with_cookies/